# KTOR DSL - how to nest templates?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to use the KTOR DSL to nest HTML templates inside one another, it seems like it should be very straightforward but the documentation has led me nowhere and nothing I've tried has compiled or worked.

I have a root-level page template defined, which expects a Placeholder called 'pageContent', and I'm trying to use routing to determine which page-level template should be injected as HTML content. So PageTemplate looks something like this:

```
class PageTemplate(private val username: String, private val displayName: String) : Template<HTML> {
    val pageContent = Placeholder<FlowContent>()
    
    override fun HTML.apply() {
        head {
            title { +"Page Title" }
            stylelink("lots of style and script, etc")
        }
        body("body classes") {
            header {...} //display logged-in user's name here, nav, etc
            main("some classes") {
                insert(pageContent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my routing looks something like this:

```
get("/example-path") {
    call.respondHtmlTemplate(PageTemplate(call.session?.username, call.session?.displayName)) {
        pageContent {
            ExamplePathTemplate(call.session?.username)
        }
    }
}
```

and the idea is to have each route overwrite pageContent with its own path-specific template.

The code above compiles. However, when I ran it, ExamplePathTemplate was never actually called. I've also tried using variations on `insert(ExamplePathTemplate(...), pageContent)` but that fails to compile on some sort of type mismatch. It feels like this should be an obvious thing I should be able to accomplish with KTOR--does anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: show your `PageTemplate` class

Comment: That's not obvious at all because of the clumsy API.

Comment: @МихаилНафталь i have updated the question with an example of the PageTemplate class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the page-specific templates to apply to page content by changing my routing to look like this:

```
get("/example-path") {
    call.respondHtmlTemplate(PageTemplate(call.session?.username, call.session?.displayName)) {
        pageContent {
            insert(ExamplePathTemplate(call.session?.username)) { }
        }
    }
}
```

This satisfies the compiler's type requirements, and successfully overwrites the pageContent placeholder with the html generated by the inserted template.

Answer (score 2):

If `pageContent` property is suppoded to be a placeholder for another template, then its type should be `TemplatePlaceholder`, not just simple `Placeholder`.

If type of `Template` is unknown in advance, then `PageTemplate` class should become generic and accept instance of `Template` as a parameter:

```kotlin
class PageTemplate<T : Template<FlowContent>>(private val username: String, private val displayName: String, private val template: T) : Template<HTML> {
    val pageContent = TemplatePlaceholder<T>()

    override fun HTML.apply() {
        head {
            title { +"Page Title" }
        }
        body("body classes") {
            header {/*...*/ } //display logged-in user's name here, nav, etc
            main("some classes") {
                insert(template, pageContent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
get("/example-path") {
    call.respondHtmlTemplate(PageTemplate(call.session?.username, call.session?.displayName, ExamplePathTemplate(call.session?.username))) {
        pageContent { //this: ExamplePathTemplate
            /*set inner template parameters here*/
        }
    }
}
```